# Go Fiber handler func error when function with dependecy injection

Tags: go, go-fiber

So I try to write code for handle func to router. But I get the error message like this "cannot use controller.UserController.FindAll (value of type func(_ controller.UserController, c *fiber.Ctx) error) as type func(*fiber.Ctx) error in argument to app.Get"

this the code.

**package route**

```
package route

import (
    "go_fiber/controller"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func RouteInit(app *fiber.App) {
    app.Get("/users", controller.UserController.FindAll ) //this line is error
}
```

**package controller**

```
package controller

import (
    "go_fiber/model/web"
    "go_fiber/service"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

type UserController interface{
    // Create(c *fiber.Ctx)
    // Update(c *fiber.Ctx)
    FindAll(c *fiber.Ctx) error
    // FindById(c *fiber.Ctx)
    // Delete(c *fiber.Ctx)
}

type UserControllerImpl struct {
    UserService service.UserService
}

func NewUserController(UserService service.UserService) UserController {
    return &UserControllerImpl{
        UserService: UserService,
    }
}

func (controller *UserControllerImpl) FindAll(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    userResponse := controller.UserService.FindAll(c)

    webResponse := web.WebResponse{
        Code:    200,
        Status: "success",
        Data:    userResponse,
    }

    c.JSON(webResponse)

    return nil
}
```

How to fix it?

**EDIT**

So this is solve. This code the solve code

**package main**

```
package main

import (
    "go_fiber/app"
    "go_fiber/controller"
    "go_fiber/repository"
    "go_fiber/route"
    "go_fiber/service"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func main(){

    db := app.NewDB()
    app.CreateDatabase(db)

    app := fiber.New()

    userRepository := repository.NewUserRepository()
    userService := service.NewUserService(userRepository, db)
    userController := controller.NewUserController(userService)

    route.RouteInit(app, userController)

    app.Listen(":3000")
}
```

**package route**

```
package route

import (
    "go_fiber/controller"


    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func RouteInit(app *fiber.App, userController controller.UserController) {
    app.Get("/users", userController.FindAll)
}
```

Comment: I suppose you'll need an anonymous function that does the call to the controller method. Could you try that

Comment: I try like this
```
func RouteInit(app *fiber.App) {
 app.Get("/users", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
  return controller.UserController.FindAll(c) // this line error
 })
}
```

but the error is not enough arguments in call to controller.UserController.FindAll
 have (*fiber.Ctx)
 want (controller.UserController, *fiber.Ctx)

Comment: `controller.UserController` is a **type**, so what you have there is a [method expression](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_expressions), but what you want is 
a [method value](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values).

Comment: so, I dont have Idea, how to fix it? I try from morning but still can't work

Comment: You'll also need to instantiate the controller. Take a look at the links by @mkopriva

Comment: yeah but I still confuse

Comment: heiii!!! Thanks for the comments!! I solve this problem, so check new my post